# Please fix this problemNotice: Undefined index: username & Password

Tags: php

I really need help from you guys to fix my php task

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\wishal_login\register.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\wishal_login\register.php on line 7
{"success":0,"message":"Kolom username tidak boleh kosong"}

this is the code I made from register.php
include_once "koneksi.php";

```
class usr{}

 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $confirm_password = $_POST;

 if ((empty($username))) {
    $response = new usr();
    $response->success = 0;
    $response->message = "Kolom username tidak boleh kosong";
    die(json_encode($response));
 } else if ((empty($password))) {
    $response = new usr();
    $response->success = 0;
    $response->message = "Kolom password tidak boleh kosong";
    die(json_encode($response));
 } else if ((empty($confirm_password)) || $password != $confirm_password) {
    $response = new usr();
    $response->success = 0;
```

Please Help..

Comment: You probably need to check that your form has been submitted before you attempt to access the POST variables.

Answer (score 0):

The username & password values don’t exist on $_POST. Dupe of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/5556498).

Debug your client side, it is most likely not sending those fields. Or at least not sending them in the body of the message.

Cheers,
Ethan

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. And, you can flag to close as a duplicate rather than linking to the dupe in a comment